# I'm working on a Hybrid app in which I'm loading HTML content in a web view inside a dialog."span" has the url value.help me

Tags: java, android, hybrid

Document html= (Document) Jsoup.parse(htmlContent);

span = ((org.jsoup.nodes.Document) html).body().
                    getElementsByAttribute("data-tap-action-                 url").get(0).attr("data-tap-action-url");

Code for opening my inbuilt browser

if (span.startsWith("http"))

{

invokeChildBrowser(span);

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a Cordova/phonegap webview and a plugin for opening URLs (e.g: InAppBrowser), otherwhise your link will be broken or will be opened in the dialog

Comment: I am using an inbuilt browser, but I cannot make my link clickable to invoke my inbuilt browser. @marcozabo

Comment: Of course you can't, another solution is  using Android WebView JavascriptInterface so you can trigger your built in browser via javascript: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: okay thanks for the help